# Why is there a default limit of five backend services in Google Cloud Load Balancing?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I just noticed that there's a limit of five backend services in Google Cloud's load balancing setup.  I'm curious in learning more about why this hard limit exists?

Is it common to reuse a backend service for multiple endpoint groups?

Comment: I guess it's by default for personal accounts. When you have a corporate account the limit is set to 400. No hard limit.

Answer (score -1):

This document lists the quotas and limits that apply to Cloud Load Balancing.

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/quotas

For backend services, quota includes "all backend services in your project" and you can review it's limit here:

GCP Console> IAM&Admin> Quotas

Filter by:

- Service ID= compute.googleapis.com
- Metric= "Backend services"
  Or
- Limit Name="Backend services"

For an HTTP(S) load balancer you can add multiple backend services and backend buckets to serve different types of content.